# why do we have to overload the '<' operator to use is_permutation and includes algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have a vector that holds a vector of points is a class that has an x and a y coordinate. I basically have to remove all the permutations and subsets from my vector. And to do that I making use of the algorithm includes and is_permutation

I have overloaded the '==' operator and it makes sense why we would need that. but those two algorithms do not work unless I overload '<' operator.

This is my point class:

```
class Point{

private:    
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Point(){
        x=0;
        y=0;
    }
    Point(int xx, int yy){
        x=xx;
        y=yy;
    }

    double getSlope(Point p){
        if(this->x!=p.x && this->y!=p.y){
            return (double)(double(this->y-p.y)/double(this->x-p.x));
        }else if(this->x==p.x){
            return INT_MAX;
        }else{
            return INT_MIN;
        }
    }   
    void print(){
        cout<<"(" <<x<<","<<y<<")";
    }
    bool operator == (Point &p){
    if(this->x==p.x && this->y==p.y )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
    bool operator < (Point &p){
        cout<<"\nin the < operator\n";
    if(this->x < p.x && this->y < p.y )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
};
```

and this is the function that takes in a temporary vector of points
and compares it with vector> to remove permutations.
The points are obtained from the file so as we're getting the points we only add it in vector> if they pass the check

```
bool check(PointVector temp, vector<PointVector> pointArrays ){

    for(int i =0 ; i < pointArrays.size(); i++){
        if(is_permutation(pointArrays[i].begin(),pointArrays[i].end(),temp.begin())){
            return false;
        }else if(includes(pointArrays[i].begin(),pointArrays[i].end(),temp.begin(),temp.end())){
            return false;
        }else if(includes(temp.begin(),temp.end(),pointArrays[i].begin(),pointArrays[i].end())){
            pointArrays[i].swap(temp);
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Point Vector is a typedef for `vector<points>;`

Comment: What error do you get without overloading `<`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is about [`std::includes`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes), which imposes a requirement upon the input sequences to be sorted (according to the comparator - `operator<`).

Under this precondition, the algorithm could be implemented with `operator==` (with the semantics of not `<` and not `>`) and the same, linear asymptotic complexity.<sup>1</sup> For the first range of length n and the second range of length m, we iterate the first range, each time comparing the element to the current element of the second range. On match, we increment the iterators to both ranges as usual. So, this is O(n+m) = O(n), because n < m => `false`. The problem is that if n > m and the result should be `false`, we must iterate the whole first range to see that (we cannot decide before checking n - m + 1 elements of the first range against the first element of the second range). The larger n - m is, the worse.

But with `operator<`, we can decide much sooner (more exactly never later), if we should return `false` from the algorithm, because we have read an element from the 2nd sequence that comes before the next one from the 1st sequence.

---

**Example:**

Is {1} a subrange of {2, ..., 10<sup>6</sup>}?

`operator==`: 10<sup>6</sup> - 1 comparisons                          `operator<`: 1 comparison

Even the `operator<` version, however, still suffers in this **example:**

Is {10<sup>6</sup>} a subrange of {1, ..., 10<sup>6</sup> - 1}?

`operator==`: 10<sup>6</sup> - 1 comparisons                          `operator<`: 10<sup>6</sup> - 1 comparisons

Then it is upon the programmer to choose the direction of iteration that is *expected* to yield shorter decision times.

**Overall, algorithms that deal with ordered sequences work in terms of order comparisons, because they provide more insight into the input sequences.**

---

<sub>1.
Without the sorted requirement (and with random-access iterators) for either range, the complexity would be higher (depending on the use of additional structures/presorting).</sub>